# PNPM How to trigger an executable package (nodemon) installed in a dependency

Tags: javascript, nodemon, npm-scripts, pnpm, pnpm-workspace

So I have 2 workspaces, "web" and "ts-service".
ts-service is a dependency of web.

In `ts-service` package I have just the package.json with:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^2.0.22",
  }
```

in `web` package.json I have this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nodemon src/index.ts"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ts-service": "workspace:*",
  }
```

this used to work in `yarn`, but I switched to pnpm and it did not worked because nodemon is not installed in this project. i ended up doing this script:

```
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "pnpm --filter ts-service -C . exec nodemon src/index.ts"
  },
```

This seems to work however it looks like that it is executing inside the ts-service and not in the  "web" as it is throwing this error:

```
Cannot find module '/home/<name>/project/packages/ts-service/index.js'
```

Now how can I make it so I can still access `nodemon` but inside `web` and pass the correct parameter which is `src/index.ts` which is inside `web`?